# How do we prove that Stochastic matrices preserve l1 norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-matrices

I have tried some previously answered questions on the forum but I don't see a formal proof anywhere. I can't understand where to begin either.

Essentially given that $A$ is a stochastic matrix and $b$ is a vector, I need to prove that $\|Ab\|_1 = \|b\|_1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Presumably $A$ is a column stochastic matrix (so that $\mathbf1^TA=\mathbf1^TA$) and $b$ is a nonnegative vector. Then $\|Ab\|_1=\mathbf1^T(Ab)=(\mathbf1^TA)b=\mathbf1^Tb=\|b\|_1$.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. $A =\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 \,\,1/2\,\\ 0\,\,\,\,\,\, 1\end{bmatrix}$ and   $b=(0,1)^{T}$ is a counter-example. Here $Ab=(1/2,1)^{T}$.